# Used vba WorkheetFunction.SumIfs method in Excel 2016. It worked fine. However, it only gave 0 values in Excel 2019 but no error message. Why?

Tags: excel, sumifs

I composed a code in vba using the Worksheet.Sumifs method.  It worked fine in Excel 2016.  When I tried to run the code again in a colleagues laptop with Excel 2019, the output had only zero values.  Initially, it felt strange...when I ran the code in another PC with Excel 2016, it worked fine.  Normally, I assumed that a older version may not be compatible with a newer version.  Here, however, it was the opposite.

I am looking for inputs if anybody else encountered such a situation.   Also, wish somebody else would try it out and offer their feedback.

Thanks.

Comment: So it does work twice in two pc’s with 2016 but not on one pc with 2019? Then the older version appears not to be compatible with the newer. But you say the opposite.

Comment: Yes, the code works in Excel 2016 but not in Excel 2019.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am getting stuck in this bit of code in Excel 2019.
     Sum_WH = Excel.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(shInvTransactions.Range("Q:Q"), shInvTransactions.Range("N:N"), "WH", _
                shInvTransactions.Range("AH:AH"), Temp_Roll, shInvTransactions.Range("J:J"), "<=" & AsOnDate)